# In windows, can I redirect stdout to a (named) pipe in command line?

Tags: windows, command-line, redirection, pipe, named-pipe

Is there a way to redirect the [standard output](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdout#Standard_output_.28stdout.29) of a process in [Win32 console](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32_console) to a [named pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#In_Windows)?
Named pipes are built in to Windows and while they would be an useful concept, I've never seen them used from command line.

Ie. like `example.exe >\\.\mypipe`. (This syntax may not be correct but you get the point.)
I would like to be able to redirect *stdout* and *stderr* to different pipes at the same time.

I would like to avoid using physical files as a substitute, to escape dealing with IO slowness, IO buffers, file locks, access rights, available hard disk space, decision to overwrite, unmeant persistence, etc.

Another reason is because the traditional Windows [set of tools](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds.mspx?mfr=true) are not designed around a (text) file based philosophy as much [as in Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Everything_is_a_file). Also, named pipes couldn't easily be mounted in Windows, if at all.

Finally, there is the curiosity if a good concept could be put into good use.

Comment: You mean like redirecting to a named pipe or a mailslot ? Do you have / are willing to write the receiving end ?

Comment: Yes, like to a named pipe or mailslot. I don't yet have but willing to write the receiving end.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not sure why you don't want to redirect to a file. There are two methods I will provide here. One method is to redirect to and read from a file, the other is a set of programs.

---

### Named pipes

What I did was write two programs for .NET 4. One sends output to a named pipe, the other reads from this pipe and displays to the console. Usage is quite simple:

```
asdf.exe | NamedPipeServer.exe "APipeName"
```

In another console window:

```
NamedPipeClient.exe "APipeName"
```

Unfortunately, this can only redirect `stdout` (or `stdin`, or combined), not `stderr` by itself, due to limitations in the pipe operator (`|`) in the Windows Command Prompt. If you figure out how to send `stderr` through that pipe operator, it should work. Alternatively, the server could be modified to launch your program and specifically redirect `stderr`. If that is necessary, let me know in a comment (or do it yourself); it's not too difficult if you have some C# and .NET "Process" library knowledge.

You can download the [server](http://www.mediafire.com/file/6sppa7r5ijomdi4/NamedPipeServer.exe) and the [client](http://www.mediafire.com/file/lt3e8bk351m55i3/NamedPipeClient.exe).

**If you close the server after connection, the client will close immediately. If you close the client after connection, the server will close as soon as you try to send something through it.** It's not possible to reconnect a broken pipe, mostly because I can't be bothered doing something so complicated right now. It's also limited to **one client per server**.

#### Source code

These are written in C#. There's not much point trying to explain it. They use the .NET [NamedPipeServerStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeserverstream) and [NamedPipeClientStream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.namedpipeclientstream).

The server:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.IO;

namespace NamedPipeServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[NamedPipeServer]: Need pipe name.");
                return;
            }
            
            NamedPipeServerStream PipeServer = new NamedPipeServerStream(args[0], System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.Out);
            PipeServer.WaitForConnection();
            StreamWriter PipeWriter = new StreamWriter(PipeServer);
            PipeWriter.AutoFlush = true;

            string tempWrite;

            while ((tempWrite = Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    PipeWriter.WriteLine(tempWrite);
                }
                catch (IOException ex)
                {
                    if (ex.Message == "Pipe is broken.")
                    {
                        Console.Error.WriteLine("[NamedPipeServer]: NamedPipeClient was closed, exiting");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }

            PipeWriter.Close();
            PipeServer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The client:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO.Pipes;
using System.IO;

namespace NamedPipeClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args == null || args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine("[NamedPipeClient]: Need pipe name.");
                return;
            }

            NamedPipeClientStream PipeClient = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", args[0], System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection.In);
            PipeClient.Connect();
            StreamReader PipeReader = new StreamReader(PipeClient);

            string tempRead;

            while ((tempRead = PipeReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(tempRead);
            }

            PipeReader.Close();
            PipeClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

---

### Redirecting to a file

```
type NUL>StdErr.temp
start powershell -c Get-Content StdErr.temp -Wait
MyExecutable.exe 2>StdErr.temp
```

1. Create an empty file
2. Start a new console window that watches the file
3. Run executable and redirect `stderr` output to that file

This provides the desired effect of one console window to watch `stdout` (and provide `stdin`), and another to watch `stderr`.

Anything that mimics `tail` would work. The PowerShell method works natively in Windows, but may be a bit slow (i.e. there's some latency between the writing to the file and the displaying to the screen). See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187587/looking-for-a-windows-equivalent-of-the-unix-tail-command) for other `tail` alternatives.

The only problem is the temporary file may grow quite large. A possible workaround is to run a loop that only prints if the file has content and clear the file immediately afterwards, but that would cause a race condition.

Comment: UNIX users are the ones that are annoyed because Windows fails yet again to implement a 40 year old idea in a sensible way. You shouldn't need to write a custom program every time you want to do a basic thing. *facepalm*

Comment: See below: you can use the UNC path assigned to a named pipe, and access it directly.

Answer (score 34):

I am surprised that this has't been answered correctly already. There is indeed a [UNC path](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) assigned to named pipes by the system, accessible on any machine in the network, which can be used like a normal file:

```
program.exe >\\.\pipe\StdOutPipe 2>\\.\pipe\StdErrPipe
```

Assuming pipes named "StdOutPipe" and "StdErrPipe" exist on this machine, this attempts to connect and write to them. The `pipe` part is what specifies that you want a named pipe.

Comment: I think this should be marked as the correct answer as Is just what is asking @n611x007 not external programs are required for doing this!

Comment: the problem is that you still need to launch a service of some kind that creates those pipes.... they do not exist independently of a program that created and are destroyed when the program goes away.

Comment: @ErikAronesty I assumed these pipes already exist. Otherwise, there is no way to create them only with cmd.exe.

Comment: Yeah that's the cool thing about unix pipes, you can create pipes from the command line

Answer (score -1):

Your preferences for a Windows pipe of data from a server to a client dos window either immediately or later might be satisfied with a small RAM drive. The same memory gets allocated for the data, written/read with a file-system-like name. The client either deletes the used-up file and waits for another, or leaves it to disappear when the computer shuts down.